# How to delete all the tab and enter in a table?

Tags: mysql

I have a big table with several `\n` (enter) and `\t` (tab) characters scattered in my data

It looks something like the following:

```
col1   col2   col3
data   \ndata data
\ndata data   \tdata
```

I need to delete all the `\n` and `\t` characters from all the columns.

Is there a simple way to do this ?

update:
when I record the table into tsv, it will be as

```
data 
\ndata data
\ndata data \tdata
```

if I simply delte all \n and \t, the tsv still look the same except the \n

```
data 
data data
data data data
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get rid of a \n at the start of a column you can run something like this:

```
UPDATE your_table SET col1 = substring(col1, -1) WHERE col1 like '\n%';
```

You can do something similar for other columns or changing \n for \t.

If you want to delete all \t and \n, anywhere on the string, you can use:

```
UPDATE your_table SET col1 = replace(replace(col1, '\t', ''), '\n', '');
```